# How to animate multiple dots moving along the circumference of a circle in Python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I'm trying to animate multiple dots moving along the circumference of their own circle using matplotlib.

I've been able to animate a single dot moving along a circle, and here's the code to do that:

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


# To make the waving flag, we need N dots moving on a circle
# Each subsequent dot is going to be delayed by a slight time, and the last dot should be the same timing as the first dot


r = 3
def circle(phi, phi_off,offset_x, offset_y):
        return np.array([r*np.cos(phi+phi_off), r*np.sin(phi+phi_off)]) + np.array([offset_x, offset_y])


plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 8,6


# create a figure with an axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# set the axes limits
ax.axis([-30,30,-30,30])
# set equal aspect such that the circle is not shown as ellipse
ax.set_aspect("equal")
# create a point in the axes
point, = ax.plot(0,1, marker="o")



def update(phi, phi_off, offset_x,offset_y):
        # obtain point coordinates
        x,y = circle(phi,phi_off, offset_x,offset_y)
        # set point coordinates
        point.set_data([x],[y])
        return point,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update,fargs=(0,8*i,0, ), interval = 2, frames=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,360, endpoint=False))
```

It looks like this :

[image: single moving dot in circle]

In order to have multiple dots, I tried to do ani.append in a loop, i.e. have it do something like this:

```
i=0
for i in range(3):
    ani.append(animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update,fargs=(0,8*i,0, ), interval = 2, frames=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,360, endpoint=False)))
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: multiple moving dots]

Any ideas on how to have multiple dots each moving smoothly on their own circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only define one update function, which is updating all points:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

r = 3
def circle(phi, phi_off,offset_x, offset_y):
        return np.array([r*np.cos(phi+phi_off), r*np.sin(phi+phi_off)]) + np.array([offset_x, offset_y])

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 8,6

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis([-30,30,-30,30])
ax.set_aspect("equal")

# create initial conditions
phi_offs = [0, np.pi/2, np.pi] 
offset_xs = [0, 0, 0]
offset_ys = [0, 0, 0]
# amount of points
N = len(phi_offs)

# create a point in the axes
points = []
for i in range(N):
  x,y = circle(0, phi_offs[i], offset_xs[i], offset_ys[i])
  points.append(ax.plot(x, y, marker="o")[0])


def update(phi, phi_off, offset_x,offset_y):
        # set point coordinates
        for i in range(N):
          x, y = circle(phi,phi_off[i], offset_x[i], offset_y[i])
          points[i].set_data([x],[y])
        return points

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update,
      fargs=(phi_offs, offset_xs, offset_ys), 
      interval = 2, 
      frames=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,360, endpoint=False),
      blit=True)

plt.show()
```

I also added the `blit=True` argument to make the animation smoother and faster (only the necessary artists will be updated) but be careful, you might have to omit this feature in more complex animations.