# Animating multiple dots in different orbits in Python using FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib

A similar question has already been answered ([How to animate multiple dots moving along the circumference of a circle in Python using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61326186/how-to-animate-multiple-dots-moving-along-the-circumference-of-a-circle-in-pytho)) but somehow it doesnt work for me.

**What Im Trying To Do**

Im trying to make little dots which represent planets orbit another dot in an ellipse. It should look something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ED-_xN9Jufs&feature=youtu.be

**The Issue I Currently Have**
[image]
(I dont know how to insert a video but heres a screenshot. The outermost dot is actually moving but the three inner ones are not)

Only the outermost planet is circling in an orbit. I know that this is because the `FuncAnimation` is within the `for j in range(1, planet_count):` loop, so I believe the last loop overwrites the previous loops. The code is down below

Please ask if you want me to clarify anything. This is the first time using FuncAnimation so I think there must be a simple solution.

Any help, even if ur unsure if its correct, would be enormously helpful and I thank you in advance.

```
planet_count = 5

df = pd.read_csv("Wincoll_prog_chall_1/data2.csv")

df["b"] = df["a"]*(1-df["Epsilon"]**2)


def position(theta, a, eps):
    r = a*(1-eps**2)/(1-eps*np.cos(theta))
    x = r*np.cos(theta)
    y = r*np.sin(theta)

    return r, x, y


num_to_color = {
    1: "orange",
    2: "pink",
    3: "green",
    4: "red",
    5: "brown",
    6: "yellow",
    7: "blue",
    8: "purple",
    9: "grey",
}



def animate(i, a, eps):
    theta = i*math.pi/180
    r = a*(1-eps**2)/(1-eps*np.cos(theta))
    x = r*np.cos(theta)
    y = r*np.sin(theta)
    planet.set_data(x, y)
    return planet,


plt.style.use('dark_background')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))


if planet_count > 5:
    ax.plot(0, 0, 'X', markersize=5, color="yellow")
else:
    ax.plot(0, 0, 'X', markersize=15, color="yellow")

# planet = []

for j in range(1, planet_count):
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*math.pi, 1000)
    r, x, y = position(theta, df["a"][j], df["Epsilon"][j])
    ax.plot(x, y, color=num_to_color[j], linewidth=2, label=df["Object"][j])

    planet, = ax.plot(x[0], y[0], '.', markersize=15, color="white")
    
    # Animation
    animation = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=360, interval=5, fargs=(
        df["a"][j], df["Epsilon"][j],), blit=True)

plt.xlabel("x", size=20)
plt.ylabel("y", size=20)
plt.legend(fontsize=12, loc="upper right", numpoints=1)
plt.grid(True, lw=0.3)
plt.show()
```

**UPDATE:**
With the help of r-beginners, I somewhat solved this. Although I cannot set the colors of the dots to the colors of the planet, it now animates nicely.

What I did was add two extra arrays, dataX and dataY, which I update every time and feed into the ax.plot. It now works very well. Thank you for that.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

AU = 149597870700
P = 5

df = pd.read_csv("Wincoll_prog_chall_1/data2.csv")

df["b"] = df["a"]*(1-df["Epsilon"]**2)


def position(theta, a, eps):
    r = a*(1-eps**2)/(1-eps*np.cos(theta))
    x = r*np.cos(theta)
    y = r*np.sin(theta)

    return r, x, y


num_to_color = {
    1: "orange",
    2: "pink",
    3: "green",
    4: "red",
    5: "brown",
    6: "yellow",
    7: "blue",
    8: "purple",
    9: "grey",
}

starting_planet = 1
planet_count = 5

if (planet_count < 6):
    anim_speed = 2.125
else:
    anim_speed = 50


def animate(i):
    dataX = []
    dataY = []

    years = round(1000*i*anim_speed/360)/1000

    for j in range(starting_planet, planet_count):
        theta = (i*anim_speed*np.pi)/(df["P"][j]*180)
        # theta = i*1/df["P"][j]*np.pi/180
        r = df["a"][j]*(1-df["Epsilon"][j]**2) / \
            (1-df["Epsilon"][j]*np.cos(theta))
        x = r*np.cos(theta)
        y = r*np.sin(theta)
        dataX.append(x)
        dataY.append(y)
        # planet.set_color(num_to_color[j])
    planet.set_data(dataX, dataY)
    title.set_text(u"Years: {}".format(years))
    return planet, title,


plt.style.use('dark_background')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
# planet, = ax.plot([], [], '.')


if planet_count > 5:
    ax.plot(0, 0, 'X', markersize=5, color="yellow")
else:
    ax.plot(0, 0, 'X', markersize=15, color="yellow")


planet, = ax.plot([], [], '.', markersize=11)


title = ax.text(0.5, 0.97, "", bbox={'facecolor': 'w', 'alpha': 0.0, 'pad': 5},
                transform=ax.transAxes, ha="center")


dataX = []
dataY = []

for j in range(starting_planet, planet_count):
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*math.pi, 1000)
    r, x, y = position(theta, df["a"][j], df["Epsilon"][j])
    ax.plot(x, y, color=num_to_color[j], linewidth=2, label=df["Object"][j])

    # planet.set_color(num_to_color[j])
    dataX.append(x[0])
    dataY.append(y[0])
animation = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1, blit=True)


planet.set_data(dataX, dataY)

plt.xlabel("x", size=20)
plt.ylabel("y", size=20)
plt.legend(fontsize=12, loc="upper right", numpoints=1)
plt.grid(True, lw=0.3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think the approach you have adopted deserves a positive evaluation. I hope you will add GIF images to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data, we created a suitable circle data and animated it. The configuration involves setting up an initial graph for animation and a fixed graph.
The animation function draws the orbit information sequentially.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np
# from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter

plt.style.use('dark_background')

n_points = 100
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_points)
e_radius = 5
m_radius = 7

x = e_radius * np.sin(theta)
y = e_radius * np.cos(theta)

xx = m_radius * np.sin(theta)
yy = m_radius * np.cos(theta)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-8, 8), ylim=(-8, 8))
earth, = ax.plot([], [], 'g.', markersize=15)
mars, = ax.plot([], [], 'r.', markersize=15)
ax.plot(0, 0, 'X', markersize=5, color="yellow")
plt.grid(True, lw=0.3)
ax.plot(x, y, 'g-')
ax.plot(xx, yy, 'r-')

def animate(i):
    earth.set_data(x[i], y[i])
    mars.set_data(xx[i], yy[i])
    return earth,mars

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100, interval=200, repeat=False)
# anim.save('cirlce_ani.gif', writer='pillow')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Thanks. That works to a certain extent but obviously when I have 9 planets orbiting, I need to repeat that code above 9 times, each time with an elif statement. Do you know of any way to maybe do it with a matrix, updating the matrix and plotting each point in the matrix? Ive tried it but Im probably lacking the experience and knowledge and only got error messages.

Comment: You can put multiple values by making it a list, but if the way each color is set is scatter, you will have to draw each color one way or the other. `earth.set_data([x[i],xx[i]], [y[i],yy[i]])`